# Joomla 1.5: why does trying to send email result in: PHPMAILER_RECIPIENTS_FAILED

Tags: windows, email, smtp, joomla

I'm trying to send emails from Joomla! 1.5.9, but keep getting this error message: PHPMAILER_RECIPIENTS_FAILED*recipient_name*<*recipient_email*>

A few more facts:

- It's a WAMP server (joomla 1.5.9, PHP 5.2.8)
- Validation emails are sent with no problem at all
- Joomla! is set to use SMTP
- The IIS SMTP service is used (though I'm not 100% sure about it's configuration)
- The diagnostics tool smtpdiag shows no problem when checking the sender/recipient

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Omer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this has already been answered before @ Joomla forums itself.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=272547

Comment: I am shameful to say that I've actually been to the page before but didn't scroll down enough to get there....
my bad

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the solutions given in the link Sukumar provided but none of them worked.

Then I tried to use PHP mail function instead of SMTP and it worked :)

Change the following line in configuration.php in the root folder

```
var $mailer = 'smtp';
```

to

```
var $mailer = 'PHP mail';
```